# Visual Studio 2010 Themes : Properties Reference

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to change the color of the vertical line of collapse/expand code. Cannot manage to find the right property in the "`Customize Colors`" Dialog in the Themes Menu.

I did not manage to find anywhere **a decent, exhaustive, and ideally visual reference for the theme properties**. I usually end-up trying blindly and changing obscurely named properties on and on, until I finally stumble on the right property by chance, or give up.

this May also be hidden somewhere in `Environment>Fonts` and Colors...

Any Ideas ?

Comment: +1 I wants...  This is sorely needed.